# In ZSH, how can I use a variable name as part of another variable name?

Tags: variables, zsh, substitution

If I have

```
readonly platform=macos
readonly val_macos=someval
readonly val_linux=otherval
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
readonly val=${val_${platform}}
```

so that 'val' gets assigned the **value** of 'val_linux' or, in this case, 'val_macos'. i.e. val will end up with the value 'someval'.

I'm sure this must be possible but I haven't been able to figure out away to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using an associative array instead? `declare -A vals=([macos]=someval [linux]=otherval)`, then `val=$vals[$platform]`.

Answer (score 0):

Indirection is expressed using `(P)`:

```
varname=val$platform
val=${(P)varname}
```